# Extracting text from APA citation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, re2

I have a spreadsheet containing APA citation style text and I want to split them into *author(s)*, *date*, and *title*.

An example of a citation would be:

```
Parikka, J. (2010). Insect Media: An Archaeology of Animals and Technology. Minneapolis: Univ Of Minnesota Press.
```

Given this string is in field I2 I managed to do the following:

Name: `=LEFT(I2, FIND("(", I2)-1)` yields `Parikka, J.`

Date: `=MID(I2,FIND("(",I2)+1,FIND(")",I2)-FIND("(",I2)-1)` yields `2010`

However, I am stuck at extracting the name of the title `Insect Media: An Archaeology of Animals and Technology.`

My current formula `=MID(I2,FIND(").",I2)+2,FIND(").",I2)-FIND(".",I2))` only returns the title partially - the output should show every character between `).`and the following `.`.

I tried `=REGEXEXTRACT(I2, "\)\.\s(.*[^\.])\.\s" )` and this generally works but does not stop at the first ". " - Like with this example:

`Sanders, E. B.-N., Brandt, E., & Binder, T. (2010). A framework for organizing the tools and techniques of participatory design. In Proceedings of the 11th biennial participatory design conference (pp. 195–198). ACM. Retrieved from http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1900476`

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title can be found (in the two examples you've given, at least) with this:

```
=MID(I2,find("). ",I2)+3,find(". ",I2,find("). ",I2)+3)-(find("). ",I2)+3)+1)
```

In English: Get the substring starting after the first occurrence of `).`, up to and including the first occurrence of `.` following.

If you wish to use `REGEXEXTRACT`, then this works (on your two examples). (You can also see a [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xF9cI5/1).):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(I3,"(?:.*\(\d{4}\)\.\s)([^.]*\.)(?: .*)")
```

> Where is the mistake?

In your expression, you were capturing `(.*[^\.])`, which *greedily includes* any number of characters followed by a character in the character class `not (backslash or dot)`, which means that multiple sentences can be captured. The expression finished with `\.\s`, which wasn't captured, so the capture group would end *before* a period-then-space, rather than including it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=split(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I2, "(",""), ")", ""),".")
```

If you don't replace the parentheses around 2010, it thinks it is a negative number -2010.

For your Title try adding index split to your existing formula:

```
=index(split(REGEXEXTRACT(A5, "\)\.\s(.*[^\.])\.\s" ),"."),0,1)&"."
```

Comment: hi ed! the year does work but i am struggling with outputting the whole length of the title that comes after ")." and is followed by another "."